# Find numbers in a string and add 50 to them

Tags: php

I want to find all the numbers in a string and add 50 to them.

So I have this to begin with:

> ```
> 'text' => string 'Word (9), WordSomething (5)'
> 'text' => string 'Word (15)'
> ```

Outcome:

> ```
> 'text' => string 'Word (59), WordSomething (55)'
> 'text' => string 'Word (65)'
> ```

Comment: Is there some easy way to tell where a number starts or ends? (like brackets)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a regex for this that captures numbers between parenthesis and then applies your own custom callback using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$result = preg_replace_callback( '/\((\d+)\)/', function( $match) {
    return '(' . ($match[1] + 50) . ')';
}, $string);
```

So, given this input string:

```
Word (9), WordSomething (5)
```

The output [will be](http://viper-7.com/UjdwVx):

```
Word (59), WordSomething (55)
```

For a variable input, use a closure:

```
$number = 50;
$result = preg_replace_callback( '/\((\d+)\)/', function( $match) use( $number) {
    return '(' . ($match[1] + $number) . ')';
}, $string);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible to use a variable for 50. I've tried double quotes i.e. $match[1] + "$number" and that doesn't work either. Any way to get 50 to be a variable?

Comment: @flux [You can add the `global $number; return ....` then it works :-)](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php#90021)

Comment: @flux - I've updated my answer to use a closure in order to allow `$number` to be a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you have an irrational fear of regular expressions, I think this should work.

Edit2: Here is the completed and working java code: http://pastebin.com/Z6uyDizz

I pseduo java code:

```
var str = "Some3people6love20code102"
var newstr = ""
var tmp = ""

for (int i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    if((int)str[i] >= 48 && (int)str[i] <= 57){
        tmp += str[i]
    }else{
        newstr+=((Integer.parseInt(tmp)+50)+"");
        newstr+=str[i] 
        tmp = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I just fixed all the code so it works in java.  It works, but given that there are brackets, a regex should be much faster.  The completed code needed a few logic modifications, such as if the string ends in a number, need to add that.  But other then that I think the logic of what is here should make this solution pretty easy to understand.  Good day everyone!

Comment: A regex also works when there are no parentheses. Simply match any repetition of digits (`\d`).

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly . :)